# Convert MySQL datetime to countdown

Tags: php, datetime

Given a datetime string like this:

```
2012-06-19 03:44:39
```

I want to use it to provide a countdown (in minutes) until that time.

```
You can post again in <?php echo date('i', strtotime($expires) - strtotime(time())) ?> minutes.
```

That's what I have, but it always says 15 minutes. Probably because `time()` isn't the right function to use but I'm not sure.

Thanks.

Comment: use jquery http://keith-wood.name/countdown.html with PHP

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`time()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.time.php) already returns a timestamp so you don't have to use `strtotime` on it:

```
<?php echo date('i', strtotime($expires) - time()) ?>
```